# ASP.NET MVC refill form data on invalid validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC project, I have made some custom fields in the view that use  input, I did not use the html helpers. When submitting the form with invalid data that is validated on the server side, not all fields are refilled automatically, only the ones that I manually added using html tags like  are reset.

How do I get the value of that select field so I can make the previous user selection the default selected value when an error occurs?

Example:
Select gender: (male | female) in a  tag
user submits invalid input and form shows error, select is at "male" again but female was selected before submitting the form, I want it to automatically be female again.

Comment: Did you try sending back the model to the View? Something like `return View(MyModel)`?

Comment: _I did not use the html helpers_ is you first mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you have to do is to send back a collection for the dropdownlist with the id for the selected option. Consider the sample application code below:

Model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer { CustomerId = 1, CustomerName = "Thor" },
                new Customer { CustomerId = 2, CustomerName = "Iron Man" },
                new Customer { CustomerId = 3, CustomerName = "Hawk Eye" }
            };
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(Customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerName");    
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Submit(Customer customer)
    {
        //Send selected CustomerId back to the view
        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(Customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerName", customer.CustomerId);
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("CustomerId")

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    }
```

So, for the `Index` action when it first hits I am populating a dropdownlist with it. When the form is submitted the selected value inside the form is posted to `Submit` action where I am getting the `CustomerId` that was selected inside the form and populating a collection with that `CustomerId` as being selected and then returning the `Index` view again.

Thus, you will see that whatever option you select from dropdown and click `Submit` you will get back to the same page but with the previous option selected. Hope it helps and here is the same code more organized: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEHPT3